# THREE.lod and normalmap shader fail

Tags: three.js

I wanted to play with THREE lod system, and I applied normal mapped material on my meshes but it failed with GL errors :

WebGLRenderingContext: GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : glDrawElements: attempt to access out of range vertices in attribute 2

Anyone can reproduce it quite easly I think, just edit the webgl_lod example, and instead of applying a MeshLambertMaterial use the normalmap ShaderMaterial provided in the misc_control_fly example.

Am I missing something, isn't the normalmap shader supposed to work with LOD meshes ?

edit:
here is links to see the problem.

original example webgl_lod that is working : http://typedef.byethost8.com/examples/webgl_lod.html

with normalmap shader from shaderLib instead of original meshLambertMateriel of web_lod example : http://typedef.byethost8.com/examples/failing_webgl_lod.html

Comment: Tip: If you really want help, do no ask the reader to create their own live example. Provide one.

Comment: I think it's more a three.js problem than my mistake, but your are right, i'm going to upload source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to generate the tangents for your geometries.
Add:

```
geometry[ 0 ][ 0 ].computeTangents();
geometry[ 1 ][ 0 ].computeTangents();
```

This will get rid of the error:

WebGLRenderingContext: GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : glDrawElements: attempt to access out of range vertices in attribute 2

Also, I had to use sheres instead of planes to see something displayed => maybe texture coordinates are not generated for planes ? Or the normalmap material does not work with planes ?

Comment: Of course, you're right ! I totaly forgot that when I went with LOD instead of my former meshes!! Thank you. normalmap was working without LODs on a planegeometry I used before (with computed tangents...), so it should still work once I computeTangents for theses.